# How do I install Apache/PHP/MySQL onto Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2

I don't know much about this but I am attempting to learn. I am on the following page:

```
     http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22
```

Firstly, which one do I download between:

```
  Unix Source: httpd-2.2.21.tar.gz [PGP] [MD5] [SHA1]
  Unix Source: httpd-2.2.21.tar.bz2 [PGP] [MD5] [SHA1]
  Win32 Source: httpd-2.2.21-win32-src.zip [PGP] [MD5] [SHA1]
  Win32 Binary without crypto (no mod_ssl) (MSI Installer): httpd-2.2.21-win32-x86-      no_ssl.msi [PGP] [MD5] [SHA1]
  Win32 Binary including OpenSSL 0.9.8r (MSI Installer): httpd-2.2.21-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8r.msi [PGP] [MD5] [SHA1]
 NetWare Binary: apache_2.2.21-netware.zip [PGP] [MD5] [SHA1]
```

Other files

I am guessing Unix but don't know quite honestly. After I download this, how do I install. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apache and PHP are already pre-installed on OS X Lion. Simply go to System Preferences and turn on web sharing. The `~/Sites` folder will automatically become your site on `http://localhost/~<local username>`.

For MySQL: it's offered as a Mac download on [mysql.com](http://mysql.com)

Answer (score 3):

This may seem strange but of the choice you've listed it's a fair bet you can eliminate the Windows and NetWare files. That leaves you with two choices, with the only difference being how they're compressed, so you could even toss a coin for it.

Answer (score 2):

unless you have some explicit reason not to, i would strongly urge you to use MAMP. It's a package that contains all the things you are looking for and requires no configuration of any kind. It just works out of the box.

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: a downvote for recommending MAMP when someone is asking how to run apache/linux/php on their mac... really? unbelievable.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but I can think of plenty of reasons not to use MAMP. The official MySQL install is quite a bit nicer IMO.

Comment: this is all very esoteric to me as Im just starting out, I appreciate everyone's imput

Comment: you're most welcome! :)

Comment: I actually totally agree, but given the question and the person saying they're "trying to learn" that's a much better place to get up and running than to try to configure everything from scratch.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel That's not how it works on Mac. Apple simply ships a default implementation which is quite a bit easier than MAMP.

Comment: Tom, as a long time Mac and MAMP user, I can assure you that you're incorrect. Trying to configure mysql to work correctly, out of the box, is not something I'd task a beginner with.  Just trying to get passwords and stuff setup will take a WHILE.  Meanwhile, MAMP just works. As I said above, I agree that it's better to use the real deal (even MAMP recommends this) but if you're just starting out, it's the much more accessible approach. And don't even get me started on httpd.conf... to say this is "easier" is just silly.

Comment: MAMP doesn't "just work". You have to jump through hoops to get your php code and your browser and your mysql database client to talk to mamp. With the official MySQL install, all of that is trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure what hoops you're referring to.

Comment: MAMP uses non standard port numbers, sockets path, default root password, etc. There is a reason we created an entire wiki page explaining how to connect Sequel Pro to a MAMP, while all other servers are covered by one simple page. MAMP is a nice package, but I honestly think it suits experience developers more than newbies.

Answer (score 2):

Apache and PHP are pre-installed. You can also install a second copy by purchasing Mac OS X Server off Apple in the Mac App Store. The free version you've already got works perfectly, but the paid one is cheap and comes with a few nice extra tools.

Apache is enabled in System Preferences -> Web Sharing (for the pre-installed one. The Mac OS X Server version comes with a separate GUI tool).

PHP is enabled by editing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and do a search for "php". The first result is a `LoadModule` command for PHP 5, which is likely to be commented out on your system. Uncomment and save changes (requires an admin password). You will need to restart apache to apply any changes to this file, easiest just to go into System Preferences -> Web Sharing and turn it off/on.

You can install MySQL from this page: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Download "Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive", it comes as an installer package, nice and easy to install.

PS: We have more detailed (and kept up to date) instructions here: http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/MySQL:Installing_on_Mac_OS_X